# Evaluating an infinite sum with the term $x^{\rho^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

When calculating asset prices with lognormal productivity, I ran into the follow expression for asset price:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \beta^i \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-\rho^{2i}}{1-\rho^2}\sigma^2\right) x^{\rho^i},
$$
where $x$ is the current productivity level. This does not look like it can be solved directly, so I tried to differentiate w.r.t. to $x$, but the results is not very satisfactory. I guess the difficulty lies in the term involving $x$. Could someone tell me whether this sum has explicit solution? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\rho > 1$ it is an example of what they call a *lacunary series*.

Not even the case $\sigma = 0, \beta=1, \rho=2$ has a known (to Maple) closed form:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2^i}
$$

Comment: In this case $\rho <1$, but I guess the answer is still no?